# Изменить значение переменной char через функцию

Tags: c++, массивы, строки, указатели

Я хочу что бы было что то вроде

```
void func(int i, char* name)
{
    if (i = 3)
    {
        std::cout << name << std::endl; //valera
        name = "anton";
        std::cout << name; //anton
    }

}
int main()
{
    static char name[] = "valera";
    func(3, name);
    std::cout << name; // anton

}
```

Но при попытке выполнить этот код у меня ошибка
`E0513 значение типа "const char *" нельзя присвоить сущности типа "char *"` 
Как мне правильно сделать код?

Comment: `i = 3`? Да, так присваивать нельзя, у вас указатель на `char*`, а вы присваиваете ему `const char[]`

Comment: Используйте `strncpy`

Comment: @EOF, а зачем в этой схеме `n`?

Comment: @Qwertiy А почему нет? Понятно что "anton" поместится. Но это может быть случайностью)

Comment: Нет смысла создавать внутри main() static-переменную. Строковые литералы - это const char*, конверсия const -> non-const запрещена без явного приведения (что крайне не рекомендуется).

Comment: дайте человеку пострелять себе в ногу.

Comment: @Πανμέτρονάριστον почему нет смысла? Или вы говорите про конкретно этот случай?

Comment: @dIm0n, потому что когда закончится main - закончится работа приложения. Какой смысл в локальном static объекте внутри main?

Comment: @Πανμέτρονάριστον не занимает стек)

Comment: @EOF, если объект большой - выдели память в куче, не извращайся.

Comment: @Πανμέτρονάριστον Это понятно. Просто как вариант ответа на Ваш вопрос)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Перефразируя из "Ивана Васильевича" - "*да сделать-то его, царь-надёжа, не мудрено*":

```
void func(int i, char* name)
{
    if (i = 3)
    {
        std::cout << name << std::endl; //valera
        strcpy(name,"anton");
        std::cout << name; //anton
    }

}
int main()
{
    static char name[] = "valera";
    func(3, name);
    std::cout << name; // anton
}
```

Только вот то ли это, что вы хотите?

Например, точно нужно присваивание, а не сравнение? :)

```
    if (i = 3)
```

Далее - нужно позаботиться, чтоб передаваемый массив имел достаточно места для размещения новой строки...